# Bluetooth with NFC chip

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

What's the point of NFC chip included in new generation of bluetooth headsets?

The ads seem to imply the phone will use it to simplify one-time initial pairing, but does it have any other function?

Answer (score 0):

[NFC is NOT bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication), it's a totally different short-range networking protocol.  You're seeing headsets support both protocols as a future-proofing tool.  (Personally, I think it's superior for a lot of applications, but then I've never been a fan of bluetooth.)

Comment: Yes, I know they are completely separate - which is why I ask what's the purpose :) They clearly not going to transmit audio via NFC, then what's that "future-proofing" for?

Comment: It's not really going to be used for audio, no, it doesn't have the bandwidth for that.  There are a lot of data transfer that it's superior for, though - such as the example you give of pairing, which when negotiated via NFC is bump and go.  Admittedly, a /headset/ isn't the best use of the technology.